# "mysql -V" and "select version()" show different versions

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu-18.04

*First of all, thanks a lot for your time!*

I upgraded MariaDB on Ubuntu 18.04 and restarted: `sudo systemctl restart mysql.server` several times.

When I run command `mysql -V` it shows:

> mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.14-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
>   using readline 5.2

When I run query `SELECT VERSION();` it shows:

> 10.1.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql` executable you have installed has a different version than the server it connects to.

- Make sure you are connecting to the correct server. Sometimes the configuration defaults file points you automatically to a remote server.
- Check where the `mysql` executable is found from using `command -v mysql` or `which mysql`. Most of the time the binary is located in `/usr/bin/mysql` so you might try invoking that directly to see if that helps.

Comment: `mysqld --version` also seems to give the correct answer.